# ng-options do not update when changing values in the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to update the data in select list but select not updating, exactly view but When I select 'test' is selected the value taken from the api even though it is not listed.

Example:

[I choose 'test'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7r4r.png)

[but selected is 'Śląsk'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rsS6.png)

**Here is my code...**

```
 <div ng-controller="selectController"
        class="form-group text-primary col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <label for="voivodeship-account-creator">Województwo</label>

<select class="selectpicker form-control-select"
        data-live-search="true" data-size="5"
        name="voivodeship-account-creator"
        id="voivodeship-account-creator"
        ng-options="region.name for region in regions track by region.id" ng-model="selectedRegion">

        <option data-hidden='true'></option>
</select>

</div>
```

JS:

```
angular
        .module('main')
        .controller(
                'selectController',
                function($scope,$http,$rootScope) {
                    $scope.selectedRegion = '';
                    $scope.regions = [
                                      {'name': 'test',
                                       'id': 1}
                                    ];
                    
                    $http.get('api/regions')
                        .then(function(response) {
                            $scope.regions = response.data;
                              console.log($scope.regions);});   
                    
                    
                });
```

JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Śląsk"},{"id":2,"name":"Małopolska"},{"id":3,"name":"Mazowsze"}]
```

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like an angular scoping issue. Angular may have created a child scope for the select part. You should attach your property to an object, which will allow you to make use of scope inheritance. So on your controller....

```
$scope.selectedRegion = {selection: ""};
```

And then in your html, change the ng-model to reflect it's now an object instead of a primitive. (In the future, try not to use primitives on your scope objects, it makes you not have to worry about dealing with scoping issues).

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control-select"
        data-live-search="true" data-size="5"
        name="voivodeship-account-creator"
        id="voivodeship-account-creator"
        ng-options="region.name for region in regions track by region.id" ng-model="selectedRegion.selection">
```

Answer (score -3):

you are missing ng-model

```
$scope.defaultSelected = {"id":1,"name":"SSS"};

    $scope.regions = [{"id":1,"name":"Śląsk"},{"id":2,"name":"Małopolska"},{"id":3,"name":"Mazowsze"}]

    $scope.addItem = function() {

        $scope.regions.push({"id":4,"name":"Dlląsk"});
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control-select"
        data-live-search="true" data-size="5"
        name="voivodeship-account-creator"
        id="voivodeship-account-creator"
        ng-model="defaultSelected"
        ng-options="region.name for region in regions track by region.id" ng-model="selectedRegion">

        <option data-hidden='true'></option>
</select>

<button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
```

[Fiddle here....](https://jsfiddle.net/naxuueq1/)

Comment: But he had an ng-model in there already. The select element now has two ng-models.